# Yoreh Yoreh vs. Yadin Yadin

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, semicha

I've heard a lot of people talking about the two different semichahs that one might receive: **יורה יורה** ("Yoreh Yoreh") and **ידין ידין** ("Yadin Yadin").
What is the difference between them?

---

*[Sourced answers preferred]*

Comment: Can I use the "[am-haaretz](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am-haaretz)" tag for this one? :P

Comment: how long does it generally take to get semicha Yoreh Yoreh? Yadin Yadin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two semicha 'tracks' cover different areas of halakah: Yoreh Yoreh covers areas that deal with the day to day questions that rabbis might receive, such as questions on [kashrut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher) or [taharat hamishpacha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nidah). Most programs of Yoreh Yoreh also include study of the laws of Shabbat and Mourning. It's traditionally associated with the second section of Tur/Shulchan Arcuh, "Yoreh Deah".

Yadin Yadin covers the type of knowledge that one would need to adjudicate cases between individuals- either in monetary or marital laws. This is traditionally associated with "Choshen Mishpat" and "Even HaEzer", the areas of Shulchan Aruch that deals with monetary and marital laws, respectively.

See the Gemara, [Sanhedrin 5a](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=sanhedrin&daf=5a&go=Go) for the origin of the names of these types of סמיכה.

> א"ל ר' חייא לרבי בר אחי יורד לבבל יורה יורה ידין ידין יתיר בכורות יתיר....יתיר בכורות אל יתיר

For more info, you can see the semicha requirements of the [Chief Rabbinate of Israel](http://www.rabanut.gov.il/show_item.asp?levelId=61638) or [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicha).

Comment: Don't forget about Yattir Yattir.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....keep forgetting about Wikipedia as a source for Jewish info ;)

Comment: Btw, Wikipedia brings an earlier source for different types of semicha -- BT Sanhedrin 5b [I glanced at it, it appears to go from amud א to ב]; mentions also the third type יתיר בכורות יתיר that @DoubleAA mentioned

Comment: @DoubleAA I've searched many years for a yeshiva or program that would grant Yatir Bechoros semicha, to no avail... if you know of one I'd love to hear about it

Comment: @Matt You got any later sources for classification of semicha? Sifrei halacha (Shulchan Aruch, Tur et al) in particular?

Comment: @Shokhet whether there are sources or not, that's what's done. The Tur doesn't say that he called the section 'Yoreh Deah' because it correlates with Yoreh Yoreh semicha, but it's likely that he had that in mind (he says he named the book as such because it offers the info needed 'lehoros'). I have seen Turkish Rabbanim (namely R. Chaim David, previous rav of Tel Aviv, but I think others too) refer to the second section of Shulchan Aruch as 'Yoreh Yoreh', which may imply that there was a tradition to associate Yoreh Deah with Yoreh Yoreh semicha

Comment: @Matt Yeah I get that's what's done...I was just wondering if there was anything more concrete than just "that's what's done"...

Comment: @הנערהזה Just asked about Yatir Bechoros semicha nowadays https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101325/why-doesnt-yatir-bechorot-yatir-semicha-exist-nowadays-ie-in-addition-to-y